# Trying to animate multiple objects of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am trying to animate (expanding bubbles) a couple of images:

```
<img src = "btn_add_friend@2x.png" class = "avatar">            
        <img src = "btn_add_friend@2x.png" class = "avatar">
        <img src = "btn_add_friend@2x.png" class = "avatar">
        <img src = "btn_add_friend@2x.png" class = "avatar">
```

Using jQuery function each() and animate() as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var av = $( ".avatar" ).toArray()
    jQuery.each(av,function (idx, avatar)
   {
      var $avatar = $(avatar);      
      $avatar.animate({height: "100px", width: "100px", left: "-=50px",top: "-=50px"}, "slow");

   })
})
```

However, what happens is, only the first element is being animated and it is like the rest of the array is never iterated through.

I would very much appreciate it if you could suggest a better way of doing it, although I really want to understand why is my code not working

Comment: `$(".avatar").each()` is way better than a `toArray` and then `each` call.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried both ways and still only the first image is being animated.

Comment: seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/r479ff1r/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your given example wouldn't work, however you have some redundancies in your code which will create unnecessary overhead. As you are already selecting all desired elements using `$(".avatar")`, and jQuery calls like this return an array, there is no need for you to cast the result to an array and iterate over its members manually. We can call the `animate` method on all elements returned by `$(".avatar")` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".avatar").animate({height: "100px", width: "100px", left: "-=50px",top: "-=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: It finally worked, I was just being stupid by styling the whole class to be located in the same place. I am now facing another problem, how do I queue them to start animating one after each other?